# Filter form on open based on value in linked subform

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a basic search page, user selects one or more values from a range of options, these are used to build a string which is then passed as the filter when the form is opened so that only the appropriate records are displayed. The form itself contains a subform.

Up to now the searching/filtering has been based on controls in the main body of the form, but I now need to be able to search one of the fields in the subform as well. Is this possible, and if so, how?

NB. I've tried executing a query to return a recordset that has the primary key of each of the records in the form I want to display but stuck on the best way to use the results. If there is only one result I can pass it as a string and it works fine, but how to handle multiple values?

Comment: For "... how to handle multiple values", does this help? `DoCmd.OpenForm "frmContacts", WhereCondition:="id IN (1,3,4)"`

Comment: Thanks, Hans. I'd ended up concatenating " OR " and then stripping the final one and that had worked but the IN syntax will be simpler I think.